# How can we loop through each column of each row in a table having 50 million rows, efficiently in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a Address Search on a sql server using soundEx and levenshtein Algorithm but looping in C# is very costly.

So thought, to write a procedure which can use SoundEx function in sql. It will compare each word in the search string with each column in every row and if found, will return the dataset to c#.

Which methos can be used to do looping/traversing the table(having 50 million rows) for such operation.

PS:
Explored cursors. They are very slow. Also, simple iterations on table itself won't do any good due to the size of table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looping in SQL is even costlier, can you solve set based? Also, I wouldn't trust `soundex` for this...

Comment: Perhaps [Full-Text Search and Semantic Search Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492213.aspx)

Comment: Maybe you can use a `MapReduce` functionality for this? or ElasticSearch?

Comment: There are lots of ways to approach this problem from a performance standpoint. Asking "how should we loop" is the wrong way to start. You shouldn't loop at all; SQL just doesn't do efficient looping.

Comment: Back in 2006, ado.net *data reader* was the most efficient looping method we found for looping through 10 million rows in SQL server 2005.

Comment: You might write a stored procedure to find a set of records that you can read into a dataset in C# and display them in a dataviewgrid.  I agree with the others - looping through 50M records is just a bad idea.